# How to load image for uitableviewcell before

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

I ve tried a lot methods while reading about my the same problem here but didn't find suitable answer and i decided to ask directly.
Here is my task. I'd like user launch my app and see cells with images which I load from web, but I see just title!

Then I scroll up and some cells are not visible on screen.

And after that I see the image only for that cell.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reusbleCell = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusbleCell];

    if (!cell) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reusbleCell];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://cs413627.vk.me/v413627067/604c/gD39fdeTH-E.jpg"];
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
        });
    });
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Text"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you lift your finger while you scroll the table view? Do images appear if you present your view controller and just wait? Your code seems ok (relating to your problem and from the first sight I don't see why it behaves like you describe based on the code you provided) so I think there's something else affecting your app. Oh, and here's great lib I always suggest for this case: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Have you searched github for asynchronous image loading in ios?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - UITableViewCell loading image asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054538/objective-c-uitableviewcell-loading-image-asynchronously)

Comment: Why don't you use AFNetworking? It has ready functions to load images. See: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a test project to check the reason,I found if you don't set the `cell.imageView.image` before return the cell, the cell.imageView.frame will be CGRectZero.So when receive the imageData,you did set the imageView.image with the imageData,but image will never be shown.

I think you can customize a UITableViewCell with a customized UIImageView.

Comment: This, probably, is the case. I'd also add that even if author fixes the issue with zero-frame, there will be visual errors due to cell reuse.

Answer (score -1):

**Problem in your code:** As told in one of answer Frame of UIImageView will be CGRectZero. So, it will not reflect whatever image you will set.

You can create custom cell and use the following code.

Replace your code with following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://cs413627.vk.me/v413627067/604c/gD39fdeTH-E.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    });
});
```

Other solution could be download image synchronously using *dispatch_sync*. But it is discouraged because it loads images lazily.

> Please note that UI should be always update on main thread.

Comment: No, it is not, dispatch_sync will just return after the block have completed execution when dispatch_async returns immediately.

Comment: jazz, better read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_sync
and then about async. You'll notice the difference=) What you suggest is conceptually wrong. It doesn't matter for main thread if a block was dispatched async or sync it will be dispatched the same way, but it only matters for the sending thread, as it will wait until block finishes execution or not.